# Access to a remote docker repository using Go

Tags: docker, go

I need to access to a private docker registry using Go and protocol V2. I need to list repositories in the private registry, get all the tags of them and another info.  Should I use docker/distribution/registry/client for that? Are there a sample for such a task? I can't find it... The official site provides only http api documentation.

I wrote some code:

```
    registry, err := client.NewRegistry("https://registry-1.docker.io/", http.DefaultTransport)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Error creating the registry: {}", err)
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    entries := make([]string, 5)

    numFilled, err := registry.Repositories(ctx, entries, "")
    if err != io.EOF {
        log.Error("Error getting the registry: {}", err)
        return
    }

    log.Info("Number of repositories: {}", numFilled)

    _ = registry
```

Of course, the docker repo needs authentication. But how should I provide it? Is there a doc for such task?

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from test code in the source package:

```
import (
    "github.com/docker/distribution/registry/client"
    "github.com/docker/distribution/registry/client/auth"
    "github.com/docker/distribution/registry/client/auth/challenge"
    "github.com/docker/distribution/registry/client/transport"
)
    
type regCredentialStore struct {
    username      string
    password      string
    refreshTokens map[string]string
}

func (tcs *regCredentialStore) Basic(*url.URL) (string, string) {
    return tcs.username, tcs.password
}

func (tcs *regCredentialStore) RefreshToken(u *url.URL, service string) string {
    return tcs.refreshTokens[service]
}

func (tcs *regCredentialStore) SetRefreshToken(u *url.URL, service string, token string) {
    if tcs.refreshTokens != nil {
        tcs.refreshTokens[service] = token
    }
}

func main() {
    creds := &regCredentialStore{username: "user", password: "pwd"}
    challengeManager := challenge.NewSimpleManager()
    _, err = ping(challengeManager, "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/", "")
    if err != nil {
        .... exit .....
    }
    transport1 := transport.NewTransport(
        nil, auth.NewAuthorizer(challengeManager, auth.NewBasicHandler(creds)))
    reg, err := client.NewRegistry("https://registry-1.docker.io/", transport1)
    ...
}   

func ping(manager challenge.Manager, endpoint, versionHeader string) ([]auth.APIVersion, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err := manager.AddResponse(resp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return auth.APIVersions(resp, versionHeader), err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fire simple http call (because it is just HTTP API) with auth header, e.g. list tags of selected image:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://"+privateDockerRegistry+"/v2/"+dockerImage+"/tags/list", nil)
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(os.Getenv("DOCKER_USER")+":"+os.Getenv("DOCKER_PASSWORD"))))
req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
...
```

Comment: Do you mean the docker api doesn't have methods for auth? Actually there is auth folder in the docker/distribution/registry/client/ but I dont know how to use it...

Comment: @denn I didn't say that. I mentioned that is HTTP api = simple HTTP call can be used for that.